# react-native map integration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to integrate google maps to my react-native application. For that I am using
**react-native-map** library.
I am getting an error while using  tag.

Here is the code I have tried:-

```
<MapView
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
  style={styles.map}
  initialRegion={{
    latitude: region.latitude,
    longitude: region.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
    longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta,
  }}

>
  <Marker
    coordinate={{
      latitude: region.latitude,
      longitude: region.longitude,
    }}
    draggable={true}
  >
    <Callout>
      <Text>Callout</Text>
    </Callout>
  </Marker>
  <Polygon
    coordinates={{
      latitude: 24.591489,
      longitude: 73.722545,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0005,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0002,
    }}
  />
</MapView>
```

This is the error I am getting :-

**Error while updating property 'coordinate' of a view managed by: AIRMapPolygon**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of LatLng like this and try

```
const [coordinates,setCoordinates] = useState([
         {
          latitude:36.778259,
          longitude: -119.417931
          },
         {
          latitude:47.751076,
          longitude: -120.740135
         }
      ])

 ...
  <Polygon
coordinates={coordinates}
 />
```